# Ruling on the game “Minecraft”

Tags: halal-haram, sihr

BEFORE YOU READ:
I already know there are some questions here and on other sites on the ruling of games and it's elements etc. But i still don't think i have found a specific answer to my question, so here goes.

Is the game Minecraft forbidden? You basically make a new world. Would that count as imitating Allah?

Not only that, there are also different types of things that questioned me, such as zombies (undead), witchcraft, enchantments, and different dimensions.

Please, i'd like a serious response, not those “it's just pixels on a screen that goes on-and-off” answers.

Answer (score -5):

I personnaly think it is halal as long as it doesnt distract you from your prayers and more, play it as long as you do not beleive that there is someone more powerful than allah.

Comment: We really appreciate you answer but try to check on [answer] we don't properly accept answer just from your thinking, and more references

Answer (score -6):

We can play minecraft but it's not haram due to pork all Muslims are blaming minecraft minecraft is good game I am also a hazarth and I am telling that all can play minecraft minecraft is not haram

Answer (score -8):

honestly as long as minecraft doesn't distract your from your salah and deen, ur good

Comment: C'mon, we need to do better than "someone on the Internet said so" answers.  Please [edit] in reliable references.